# how to invoke a terminal/powershell in a remote machine using python

Tags: python, django, terminal

am doing a project in Django I want to invoke a terminal in another machine to execute the code and how can I pass the the arguments to that terminal using python

Comment: It's sound like a really bad idea. Why do you want to do that ? Can you give more details ? Can you put a program listening on a port on your remote machine ?

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way to execute functionality on a remote machine to use subprocess module to open a ssh session on the remote site, and remember to set up ssh on both machines, firewalls etc. When you start ssh you tell it what command to execute and the parameters for that command.

I wouldn't open a general terminal session up that you type commands into - that sounds like a really bad idea.

I am not going to include code here - for obvious reasons.